# Div appear and disappear onclick in React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to show the [content on the *cards*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4nWz.jpg) (marked in red and named `product.description` in the code) on click but I don't know any way of doing it.

The content on the card is fetched from JSON-server.

**Here is some code**

> The first js is used to fetch the data from the server and display
> that on the page and the second one is the method of showing the data
> on the page. In general, I want the **p** tag to appear and disappear
> when the user clicks on the main div named `Product-Preview`

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ProductList from "./ProductList";

const Products = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState (null);

    useEffect (() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/products')
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                setProducts(data);
            })
    }, []);
    
    return ( 
        <div className="ProductList">
            {products && <ProductList products={products}/>}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Products;
```

```
const ProductList = (props) => {
    const products = props.products;


    return ( 
        <div className="ProductList" >
            {products.map((product) => (
                <div className="Product-Preview" key={product.id}>
                    <div className="backdrop" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${product.image})`}}></div>
                    <h2>{ product.title }</h2>
                    <p>{ product.description }</p>
                    <div>{ product.price }</div><br />
                </div>
                
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default ProductList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a component and use a state in this component to do it.

Example component has a name is `Card`

```
const Card= ({ product }) => {
  const [showDescription, setShowDescription] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div
      className="Product-Preview"
      onClick={() => setShowDescription(!showDescription)}
    >
      <div className="backdrop" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${product.image})` }}></div>
      <h2>{product.title}</h2>
      {showDescription && <p>{product.description}</p>}
      <div>{product.price}</div>
      <br />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And use this component inside map

```
{
  products.map((product) => <Card product={product} key={product.id} />);
}
```